# Probability that a patient is infected if test result says so with 0.8 probability

Tags: conditional-probability

Patients of a clinic are tested for a particular desease. For each patient, the result of the test – ‘infected’/’not
infected’ – is correct with the probability 0.8. Suppose that 20% of the patients are infected. What is the
probability that a given patient is indeed infected if his/her test result shows ‘infected’?
◦ 0.4
◦ 0.5
◦ 0.6
◦ 0.64
◦ 0.8

I suppose the answer is 0.8 since that is the probability that a result is accurate.

Comment: See this similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491146/probability-that-a-person-is-infected-if-test-is-positive

Answer (score 0):

Writing $+/-$ for "test positive/negative" and $I/J$ for "infected/not infected", then letting $P(I\cap+)=u$ and $P(J\cap-)=v$, we have
$$\begin{array}
&&I&J\\
+&u&u/4\\
-&v/4&v\end{array}$$
from which we derive the system
$$u+v/4=0.2\\
u/4+v=0.8$$
and solving gives $u=0,v=0.8$. Thus $P(I\mid+)=0$, which is not one of the given answers. A number or two must have been transcribed incorrectly.